# Failed to open Virtual Machine Manager

Tags: kvm, ubuntu-server

I have Ubuntu Server 16.04. and I have installed kvm for VM managing.

To connect to UI of that server I'm using vnc.

Everything worked ok till last week when suddenly "Virtual Machine Manager" refuse to be opened.

To resume, I connect to server over vnc like always and I try to open "Virtual Machine Manager" from Applications and nothing happens, no error, no notification.

Also when I check over terminal in syslog/messages/... there is no error.

When I execute virt-manager over terminal also nothing happens.

I have tried to uninstall and install all kvm packages including virt-manager but issues is still there.

I did get on first this errors when I ran virt-manager:

```
[10:23]server*ROOT: ~/kvm  virt-manager     
[10:23]server*ROOT: ~/kvm  Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(virt-manager:14311): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
```

But then I executed export DISPLAY=:1 and error has gone.

I know there is "terminal way" but I like more to visually manage my VM's.

Thank you for help in advance